# DailyCodingProblems: f parameter/function

Tags: python

So i'm working on the daily coding problems and the one i got today got me stumped.

> cons(a, b) constructs a pair, and car(pair) and cdr(pair) returns the
>   first and last element of that pair. For example, car(cons(3, 4))
>   returns 3, and cdr(cons(3, 4)) returns 4.
>
> Given this implementation of cons:
>
> ```
> def cons(a, b):
>     def pair(f):
>         return f(a, b)
>     return pair
> ```
>
> Implement car and cdr.

I don't understand what the "f" represents.
I tried printing the thing i get from that function:

```
x = cons(3, 4)
<function cons.<locals>.pair at 0x2adc0ec45ae8>
```

But i still don't understand what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to research how decorators work

Comment: @asynts The implementation OP provided is a template (`"Given the implementation of .... implement ..."`). It's basically a decorator with 2 arguments

Comment: @asynts Also, if `f` is implemented in such a way that it returns a function then it's a perfectly valid implementation which is basically equivalent to the `lambda` in yours

Comment: @asynts for example, using OP's implementation of `cons`: `@cons(3, 4);def car(*t): return lambda: t[0]`  then `print(car())` will output `3`

Comment: @asynts We are getting a bit of topic here, but decorators are basically a syntactic sugar for `a(b(...z()))`

Comment: So pair is the decorator, cons is the function to pass arguments to f a function which returns a and b?

Comment: `@cons(3, 4); def car(first, last): return first`
`x = car(cons(3, 4))`
I think i understand, when i call just `cons(3, 4)` the pair function defined in cons is not going to be call. However if i call `car(cons(3, 4))` since i put cons as a decorator, it is going to execute the pair function giving me access to the a and b variables.
But i get an error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` when trying to assign to x.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine `cons`:

```py
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair
```

So calling `cons(3, 4)` dynamically creates a function as if you statically define it like this :

```py
def pair_3_4(f)
    return f(3, 4)
```

Similarly :

```py
pair1 = cons(2, 6)
pair2 = cons(5, 8)
pair3 = cons("a", "b")
```

is equivalent to :

```py
def pair1(f)
    return f(2, 6)
def pair2(f)
    return f(5, 8)
def pair3(f)
    return f("a", "b")
```

Now, let's examine `pair`:

```py
def pair(f):
    return f(a, b)
```

From this, you can guess that `f` must be a callable object, and that it takes two arguments. The most simple callable object is a function, so let's say that `f` is a function.

Also you can see that `pair` simply calls `f` with whatever `a` and `b` were bound to it by `cons`.

Here is an example where I use `print` as the `f` :

```py
>>> pair_3_4 = cons(3, 4)
>>> pair_3_4(print)
3 4
>>> cons(3, 4)(print)
3 4
>>> print(3, 4)
3 4
```